# Authentication Library Config Type Only Import Causes Reference Error

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular17, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have an authentication library designed to keep auth stuff consistent across various webapps, inspired by the angular-oauth2-oidc library. I am running into an issue when testing my app, however. In the implemented auth service (employee-auth.service.ts), which extends the library auth service, I get a "ReferenceError: AuthLibConfig is not defined."

I finally discovered that the issue was that the import of the library config, at the behest of eslint, is type only. I am looking for some insight on why a type only import is not sufficient and why it is causing this reference error.

This does not work, but satisfies eslint

```
import { AUTH_CONFIG_TOKEN, type AuthLibConfig, AuthLibService } from '../auth-lib';
```

This does work, but yields an eslint error

```
import { AUTH_CONFIG_TOKEN, AuthLibConfig, AuthLibService } from '../auth-lib';
```

Here's a stackblitz and directions to reproduce:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-n8o79p

Wait for Stackblitz container to install deps

- Ctrl+C the served application
- Run ng test
- Expected behavior
- I expect the test to pass without reference error. type can be removed from the import statement to produce a passing test.

I am using ng-mocks; I was worried about it being a bug with their MockBuilder, but I stripped it all out for a stock angular unit test and it didn't make a difference.

I've tried providing the AuthLibConfig in the test and creating an instance of the AuthLibConfig directly in the test, but it still remains undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, TS understands `AuthLibConfig` is only used as a `type` in that specific file, but we know `AuthLibConfig` is more than just a `type` as per its usage across the project. So we cannot export it as `type`

If we import it as `type`, `AuthLibConfig` references in that file are not processed at test runtime and it is disconnected from its actual bundled definition, thereby resulting in test failure.

It is like a tug of war between TS focusing on the single file vs Angular focusing on the whole project, and neither is willing to give up how they function without a fight.

---

**Option 1:** Relax the TS eslint rules for [consistent-type-imports](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports/) but it can cause issues if future code is not handled properly.

(or)

**Option 2:** Rewrite the injected services using `inject` method as below,

FROM

```
...

export class EmployeeAuthService extends AuthLibService<Employee> {
  public constructor(
    @Inject(HttpClient) private readonly http: HttpClient,
    @Inject(OAuthService) oauth: OAuthService,
    @Inject(AUTH_CONFIG_TOKEN) config: AuthLibConfig
  ) {
    super(oauth, config);
  }
  ...
}
```

TO

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core'
...

export class EmployeeAuthService extends AuthLibService<Employee> {
  private readonly http = inject(HttpClient)
  oauth = inject(OAuthService)
  config = inject(AUTH_CONFIG_TOKEN)
  ...
}
```

This will remove the need for using `AuthLibConfig` as `type`. But you may have to change it on all files, for better consistency/readability.